# If i already know the Voronoi vertices points, how can i create a polygon from the list?

Tags: voronoi, game-maker, game-maker-language

I'm trying to create this in Gamemaker. I already know the Voronoi vertices but i'm stuck with how to create polygons for each seed object. I need them to be independent so i can split it up later to apply texture mapping to them.

I've tried delaunay already but it doesn't seem as accurate as my voronoi generation. But being that the cicrumradius is the voronoi vertices anyways i feel like i don't need it. The problem with the Delaunay is that it only returns the points near the center of the diagram and doesn't return any points towards the Borders of the Box. The only good thing is that delaunay did skip an extra step and made it easier to return if the the seeds x and y are within the circumradius then just add them to the list of vertices

Is there any way to make a polygon from a plot of points from a data structure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting polygons from voronoi edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869737/getting-polygons-from-voronoi-edges)

Answer (score 0):

Pick the midpoint of each edge and the distance to each site then sort the result and pick the first and second (when they are equal) and save them into polygons. For the borders there is of course only 1 edge.
Duplicate:[Getting polygons from voronoi edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869737/getting-polygons-from-voronoi-edges)